# Baking two strata at once

Tags: breakfast

I want to offer a veggie and a meat strata at a brunch for a large group. They both require the same oven temperature. Can I bake them at the same time, and if so, what adjustments do I need to make? Thanks!

Comment: I'm not entirely sure what you're asking. Do the two recipes call for different temperatures? Will they fit in the oven at the same time? As a rule, strata is fairly forgiving. If the two recipes call for different temperatures, you can probably just split the difference.

Comment: They require the same temp. I just wasn't sure if they would bake differently if together in the oven. So, use the same temp and the same time?

Comment: Same temp, they may need a bit more time just because you've got more mass to heat. Give yourself a few extra minutes and rotate your pans halfway through.

Answer (score 1):

When you put one item in the oven, the size affects the cooking time, because the thicker it is, the longer it takes for the heat to reach the middle. But if you put two things in, that's not a concern, unless they're so close together that they're basically "acting like" one big thing.

According to [this site](http://www.newton.dep.anl.gov/askasci/gen01/gen01305.htm), "The oven has a thermostat that keeps its temperature fairly constant, no matter what is placed in it (within reason). As long as the objects in the oven don't absorb so much heat that the oven can't keep up (or are so big as to prevent even circulation), it is unlikely that the number of things placed in the oven will affect the cooking time. It will take more heat to cook more mass that is placed in the oven, so the flame (or electric heating element) will be on more."

Don't forget that cooking times in recipes are always estimates, as some ovens hold temperature more tightly than than others; most aren't that accurate, and run hotter or colder than set; different sized ovens have different airflow; and food cooks differently at different altitudes. Always check the food when it's "supposed" to be done (or slightly before) and adjust accordingly!

Comment: It's really pretty easy for them to be big enough to affect circulation, though. For example if you bake a sheet of cookies on top and bottom, the ones on top will tend to brown less on the bottom, since they're shielded by the sheet below. The overall temperature of the oven might be the same, but the distribution through the oven isn't.